# How to generate colorPrimaryDark programmatically given the primary color?

Tags: android, material-design

How to generate a dark shade color from primary color and set the status bar color with it? keep in mind that if the color is bright the icons should be dark and vise versa

Comment: do you want to setstatusbar color or do you want to generate darker shade of a given color

Comment: I want to generate darker shade of a given color but this darker color should follow material guide lines for generating colorPrimaryDark colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such guidelines for generating colorPrimaryDark. It just has to be a darker shade to the primary color. Here is the code for generating a darker shade of a given color

```
public static int manipulateColor(int color, float factor) {
    int a = Color.alpha(color);
    int r = Math.round(Color.red(color) * factor);
    int g = Math.round(Color.green(color) * factor);
    int b = Math.round(Color.blue(color) * factor);
    return Color.argb(a,
            Math.min(r,255),
            Math.min(g,255),
            Math.min(b,255));
}
```

factor represents how much you want to darken it, pass anything between 0-1

Answer (score -1):

You can change color of status bar as:-

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)                                               
            {
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.anycolor));              

            }
```

Comment: I don't think this is a wrong answer and it should not be down voted. According to the question that was asked it is a right answer. 3 users have given similar type of answer. If you are not satisfied with the answer then there is a problem in asking the question. Moreover now the question is edited. So, according to the previous question this is a suitable answer..